# Codeigniter 3.x.x dynamic session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

What I'm trying to do is match a user's IP, if match set session to 1 year or unlimited, if not match set session to 15 minutes.

Already searched and tried suggestions online, but still failed to do it and wasted several hours.

Is there anyway to do this in Codeigniter 3.x.x??

Here my config file settings.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'joel_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have some parent controller that is extended by all logged in controllers/methods, in config file, you can set expiration to 600 and in constructor of parent controller you can set `$this->session->mark_as_temp('session_matched_variable', 31622400);` for any variable you need.

Comment: @Tpojka I searched about mark_as_temp and found It was useful, thank you

Comment: Yup. Always have [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/) open.